# Can I pass a DataTable to my SQL statement (INSERT)?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Suppose I have the following structures:

**SQL Table**

```
[Person Table]
-----------------------------------
Name | Gender | Age
-----------------------------------
     |        |
```

**ADO.Net**

```
[DataTable]
--------------------------------
Name | Gender | Age
--------------------------------
John | M      | 18
Peter| M      | 20
```

Given my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = getConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person VALUES(@Name, @Gender, @Age)", conn);
conn.Open();

...
```

Is there a way to pass my whole DataTable as a parameter in my program?

Thanks.

Comment: there's really no need to include things like "C#" in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

```
string insertFields = "";
string insertValues = "";
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            insertFields += col.ColumnName + ",";
            insertValues += "@" + col.ColumnName + ",";
        }
//chop off ending comma here with substring.

string sql = "INSERT into T " + insertFields + " VALUES(" + insertValues + ")";


    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>;
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter(col.ColumnName, dr[col.ColumnName]));
        }
        //Execute cmd with sqlparams. May need to set property as sqlParams.ToArray()
    }
```

Comment: **YIKES!!** Concatenating together a SQL INSERT statement.... doors is **wide open** for SQL injection attacks ..... stop doing that! Use parametrized queries!

Comment: It seems to be a parametrized query.